# How to write to database with condition?

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli, conditional-statements

I'm beginner in PHP and I have problem write to database with condition. I have array with variables. And variables which have value 1 I need to save in to database. Some of the other variables can have value 0 or 5 and as I said 1 too.

Array with variables:

```
<?php session_start();    
        $qA01_1 = $_SESSION['qA01_1'];     
        $qA01_2 = $_SESSION['qA01_2'];
        $qA01_3 = $_SESSION['qA01_3'];
        $qA01_4 = $_SESSION['qA01_4'];
        $qA01_5 = $_SESSION['qA01_5'];

        $qA02_1 = $_SESSION['qA02_1'];     
        $qA02_2 = $_SESSION['qA02_2'];
        $qA02_3 = $_SESSION['qA02_3'];
        $qA02_4 = $_SESSION['qA02_4'];
        $qA02_5 = $_SESSION['qA02_5'];

        $qA03_1 = $_SESSION['qA03_1'];     
        $qA03_2 = $_SESSION['qA03_2'];
        $qA03_3 = $_SESSION['qA03_3'];
        $qA03_4 = $_SESSION['qA03_4'];
        $qA03_5 = $_SESSION['qA03_5'];

        $qA04_1 = $_SESSION['qA04_1'];     
        $qA04_2 = $_SESSION['qA04_2'];
        $qA04_3 = $_SESSION['qA04_3'];
        $qA04_4 = $_SESSION['qA04_4'];
        $qA04_5 = $_SESSION['qA04_5'];

        $qA05_1 = $_SESSION['qA05_1'];     
        $qA05_2 = $_SESSION['qA05_2'];
        $qA05_3 = $_SESSION['qA05_3'];
        $qA05_4 = $_SESSION['qA05_4'];
        $qA05_5 = $_SESSION['qA05_5'];
?>
```

and here is my attempt to write in database with condition (not work):

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'database');
        $varValue = 1;
        $values = [];
        foreach([1,2,3,4,5] as $index) {
           if(['$qA01_'.$index] == 1) {
               $values[] = "('$qA01_{$index}')";
           };
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO table ($varValue) VALUES ". implode(',',$values);  
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Can you help me please with correct code, please ?

[Here is old table where are together value 0, 1, 5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a42lF.png)

And now I would like to have three tables. The first for values 1 "tableOK", second for value 5 "tableNOK" and third like info table "tableinfo".

[Three new tables created in Excel and my wishes in phpMyAdmin (my proposal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jcgd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the new structure, assuming that the fields by default have value 0:

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Error connection: (" . mysqli_connect_errno().")";

$values = [];
$fields = [];
for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++)
{
    foreach([1,2,3,4,5] as $index) 
    {
        if(${'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index} == 1) 
        {
            $values[] = ${'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index};
            $fields[] = 'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index;
        }
    }
}
$query = "INSERT INTO tableOK(".implode(',',$fields).") VALUES (". implode(',',$values).")";

if( !  mysqli_query($connect, $query))
{
    echo "Error query: ".mysqli_error($connect)
}
```

This checks all `$qA01_...` to `$qA30_...`.

Comment: Dear Nerea, I've tried to replace your proposal "if condition" but nothing saved in database. Can I have issue in last two rows ?

Comment: @Nezdecek in your query `INSERT INTO table ($varValue)`  try to change the `$varValue` for the name of the field in the database, also check that you are changing the word table for the name of the table, and first of all check that you get into the if condition. If still not work post the result of `echo $query`.

Comment: I updated the answer, I thought that you want to save into the database the value of `'$qA01_'.$index`, then I see that you want to save this variable as text, am I right?

Comment: I added more info (pictures with tables created in excel) to original question. Hope it could be a little bit clear :) . Thank you very much for help. By the way: qA01_1 up to qA30_5 are all the time variables. Their values could be numbers 0 or 1 or 5.

Comment: thank you for update.  "Echo $query;" looks fine:  INSERT INTO tableok qA01_1,qA04_4,qA09_4,qA14_1,qA16_2,qA17_5,qA18_2,qA21_5,qA24_2 VALUES 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1. But "tableok"  in phpMyAdmin is empty.  I don't why values are not pasted into database.

Comment: @Nezdecek, in the query are missing the `()` that wraps the values, my mistake. I updted the answer and add some lines so you can see if there is another problem with the query or the connection

Comment: It work :) ! Thank you very much. I`ve added table for "tableNOK" and work too.

Comment: is it possible to change your code? My idea is without writing to database. Only simple sum of all numbers 1 from array.